# How to read data from Firebase database that have rules- Android

Tags: android

I just start working with firebase and im working on a project that user can Mark clinic appointments so i add some rules on firabase. Only the owner can read and write his own appointments.
I can write to firabase with no problem, but i cant read from it.
 this is my code:

this is how i fetch th data

```
 Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL).child("Consultas");


ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    Consultas consulta2 = postSnapshot.getValue(Consultas.class);
                    String  consulta1 = "Consulta de: "+consulta2.getNomeconsulta()+"\n";
                    String  medico1 = "Com o Médico: "+consulta2.getNomemedico()+"\n";
                    String  data1 = "Marcada para: "+consulta2.getHorario()+"\n\n";
                    String  time = "Marcada para: "+consulta2.getTime()+"\n\n";

                    textView1.setText(consulta1);
                    textView2.setText(medico1);
                    textView3.setText(data1);
                    textView4.setText(time);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

This are my rules on firebase

```
{
    "rules": {
      // User profiles are only readable/writable by the user who owns it
      "users": {
        "$UID": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $UID",
          ".write": "auth.uid == $UID"
        }
      },
//         Posts can be read by the user who owns it/ written by the user who owns it.
      "Consultas": {
        "$UID": {
        ".read":  "auth.uid == $UID",
        ".write":  "auth.uid == $UID"
        }
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: does 
                    textView1.setText(consulta1);
                    textView2.setText(medico1);
                    textView3.setText(data1);
                    textView4.setText(time);
display data

Comment: Only when the read are true

Comment: @EudesInácio Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: yes i did. when the user save the appointments, it saves under his id on firebase. so the path is like that:  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointments").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
this way the user only sees his appointments

Comment: for this problem I did not use firebase rules

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseRules user `===` to equal values, you should change your code to:

```
   {
    "rules": {
      // User profiles are only readable/writable by the user who owns it
      "users": {
        "$UID": {
            ".read": "auth.uid === $UID",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $UID",
        }
      },
//         Posts can be read by the user who owns it/ written by the user who owns it.
      "Consultas": {
        "$UID": {
        ".read":  "auth.uid === $UID",
        ".write":  "auth.uid === $UID",
        }
        }
    } 
}
```

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?hl=es)

Comment: I eddited the answer, I forgot two commas. It should work. Anyway, give a look to an already created rules, maybe you are overwriting your own rule with a condition in a upper level. Check this as example:
https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json